# Firebase and Universal Links collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, ios-universal-links, firebase-remote-config

I have an app that uses Firebase Remote Config and also it supports Universal Links.
When I configure Firebase in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with this line of code `[FIRApp configure]` the support for Universal Links stops working. More precisely `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler` never gets called.

I don't use Firebase Deep Links and don't have them implemented.

Any thoughts on how to stop Firebase from taking over the control of the mentioned delegate method?

Comment: This is happening for me too. I'm specifically using Branch.io for my links. I have an app in Swift and one in Objective C. This works fine in Swift but breaks as the OP described in Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled set to NO (Boolean) in your Plist.

Also, You might should manually set the APNS token.