# AppDelegate ContinueUserActivity not called when launching app from deep link, Firebase SDK is to blame

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

In my AppDelegate class I'm trying to handle deep links that launch my Xamarin iOS app, so that I can navigate the user to the proper place in the app based on the url. I'm overriding all of the ContinueUserActivity and OpenUrl methods, however none of these methods are ever called (either when the app is closed or just suspended.) I'm testing by including the deep link (https://example.com/path1/path2) in a iOS Calendar event, then tapping on the link on my iPhone 6 (running iOS 12.3.1) while the app is running in debug mode. My app does open when the link is tapped, but none of the break points are hit in any of the overridden methods.

```
public override bool ContinueUserActivity (UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler) {
            return true;
        }

    public override bool OpenUrl (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSUrl url, Foundation.NSDictionary options) {
                return true;
            }

            public new bool OpenUrl (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSUrl url, UIKit.UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions options) {
                return true;
            }

            public override bool OpenUrl (UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation) {
                return true;
            }
```

I think that the universal links are set up correctly (associated domains, etc...), otherwise it wouldn't be launching my app. Also, I've confirmed that my FinishedLaunching method returns true, as I read elsewhere that if this returns false then ContinueUserActivity and OpenUrl aren't called. Other overridden methods in AppDelegate like OnActivated and WillContinueUserActivity are called, but not the ones that I need to get at the deep link url.

Is this a Xamarin iOS bug? Or is there something I'm doing incorrectly? I'm using the latest version of Xamarin iOS (12.8.0.2).

EDIT: A little more info... It turns out that the Firebase SDK is to blame for breaking deep links. If I disable it, then clicking on a deep link will successfully call ContinueUserActivity. However, as soon as I call Firebase.Core.App.Configure(), then subsequent deep link clicks will still open the app but no longer call ContinueUserActivity. I'm not sure how to work around this issue, as I need Firebase for Analytics (Google Analytics is going away soon...)

Comment: You may also need [WillContinueUserActivity:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiapplicationdelegate.willcontinueuseractivity?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UIApplicationDelegate_WillContinueUserActivity_UIKit_UIApplication_System_String_) and [DidFailUserActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiapplicationdelegate.didfailtocontinueuseractivitiy?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UIApplicationDelegate_DidFailToContinueUserActivitiy_UIKit_UIApplication_System_String_Foundation_NSError_) if `WillContinue` returns false, `DidFail` may be called.

Comment: @NSGangster I'm not sure what you mean by if WillContinue returns false. If I override WillContinueUserActivity, I need to return true or false myself. Even if I return true, ContinueUserActivity is never called.

Comment: So WillContinueUserActivity gets breakpointed?Did you check if it failed?

Comment: Yes, WillContinueUserActivity hits the breakpoint. I'm not sure what you mean by if it failed or not. It simply overrides that method, and then I need to return true or false. I can't call base.WillContinueUserActivity to see what the result of that would be, because that throws an exception stating that you can't call the base method.

Comment: There is another method, [`DidFailUserActivity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiapplicationdelegate.didfailtocontinueuseractivitiy?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UIApplicationDelegate_DidFailToContinueUserActivitiy_UIKit_UIApplication_System_String_Foundation_NSError_), if you override this and breakpoint it you can see the `NSError` that should give you more info on why it is failing. If your `ContinueUserActivity` isn't being called, it is likely a breakpoint will hit the `DidFailUserActivity` method.

Comment: @NSGangster Thanks for the tip, however DidFailToContinueUserActivity is not hit by a breakpoint.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @AndrewMcKinley I logged a bug in the Firebase repo but they ignored it. We ended up reverting back to Google Analytics for now, but this isn't much of a solution because they're retiring their mobile solution in favor of Firebase soon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666019/firebase-and-universal-links-collision/53302596#53302596 This fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit goes to @Andrew McKinley, but for others who run into the same issue the resolution is to add a new key to your Info.plist file:

Key: FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled
Type: Boolean
Value: No (false)

After that Firebase stops hijacking handling of deep link urls, so AppDelegate.ContinueUserActivity is correctly called when a deep link is clicked.